# Comparing two tables (what one table has that the other does not)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables called FICA11, FICA7. Now FICA7 is old records of clients, and fica11 is new records, we call it maintenance records.

What I need to do on a monthly bases is see what new documentation came in from FICA11 that was not in the fica7 table(maintenance records)

***sample data FICA7***

```
ID Number    Document_Type
2456525425625,other
2456525425625,POA
2456525425625,POA
2456522456585,other
2456522456585,id
1245879566554,other
1245879566554,ID
```

***sample data FICA11***

```
    ID Number    Document_Type
    2456525425625,other
    2456525425625,id
    2456525425625,POA
    2456522456585,other
    2456522456585,id
    1245879566554,poa
    1245879566554,ID
```

Now what I must able to see is how many new ID we now have from FICA11 that we did not have in FICA7

From the above example.

```
New ID    1           
New POA   1
New Other 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` + `Group By` + `Count`:

```
SELECT Document_Type, Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM FICA11 f11
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM FICA7 f7
    WHERE f11.Number = f7.Number
      AND f11.Document_Type = f7.Document_Type
)
GROUP BY Document_Type
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using left outer:-

```
SELECT F11.Document_Type, count(f11.document_type) - Count(f7.document_type) AS Count
FROM FICA11 f11 LEFT OUTER JOIN FICA7 f7 ON f11.ID_Number = f7.ID_Number AND f11.Document_Type = f7.Document_Type
GROUP BY f11.Document_type
```